# how to create map that moving in cycle

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

all. I need to create some map that will be moving in cycle. How can i do this.
For some parts of my game i use very long tmx map.
But now i need to repeat some texture forever.
for tmx map i use :

```
self.tiledMap =[CCTMX tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"mapLOng1.tmx"];//map width=device width map height=20000 px
moveMapAction = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:300.0 position:ccp(0,-20000)];
[self.tiledMap runAction:moveMapAction];
```

it's work perfect
but how can I repeat this map? (when map end start map from beginning)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Ray's tutorial on How to Make a Space Shooter. I think it has just the thing you're looking for.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game